# Calling object class method which in a vector inside another object class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to group multiple class into a class.
Now I'm facing a problem to call a class method which in a vector inside another class.

Here is my structure:

```
class Group
{
    public:
       void PushCharacterToVector(Character character);
    private:
        vector<character> characterList;
}

class Character
{
    public:
        Character();
        void SetName(string name);
    private:
        string _name;
}
```

When there is no `Group` class, `characterList` was declare in the `main()`, I was able to call class method by using `characterList[i].SetName("XX")`.

Since I need to declare this `characterList` inside `Group` class. I would like to do an action like this

```
Group _group;
_group.PushCharacterToVector(Character());
//Set name to a character inside Group vector
_group.characterList[0].SetName("Kelvin"); //My concept to do
```

Comment: Why does `Group` inherit from `Character`? That looks unnatural for me. Also provide a [MCVE] that exactly reproduces the problems you face with your code please. You currently don't have any `public` function to access `characterList`, show an attempt please.

Comment: I'm not sure about it. I Googled a lot and most answers are telling me to use inherit. Should I not using it?

Comment: You googled what? Is a group a character?

Comment: Whenever you make a member private you can’t access it. If you want to access it make it public.

Comment: I edited my question. I would like the `characterList` be private. Should I return this `characterList` by using `GetCharacterList` and put it back by using `SetCharacterList`. Is there a one step to do so?

Comment: @KelvinLow Why not provide another public function in `Group` that takes two parameters, `index` and `name`? A simple getter/setter doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @user0042 I was thinking there is something like inherit so that I don't have to create a new function. Is this the only way to do so?

Comment: @KelvinLow _"Is this the only way to do so?"_ Yes. You may add some syntactic sugar by overloading the `operator[]` of `Group`, but it's still a function you have to write. No giveaways with inheritance here.

Comment: @user0042 Too bad =( BTW Thank you a lot, you can answer this question at below

Comment: Voted to close because it's too broad. There are dozens ways to achieve your goal, and choosing the right one depends on what your design goals are.

Comment: @ChristianHackl OK. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Add method that returns reference to `characterList`:

   ```
   class Group
   {
       public:
           vector<Character>& getCharacterList () {
               return characterList;
           }

       private:
           vector<Character> characterList;
   }
   ```

   Then in `main ()`:

   ```
   ...
   Group group;
   ...
   group.getCharacterList ()[i].SetName("XX");
   ```

   Note, however, that this is not a good while possible solution. This solution may be considered bad, because it does not provide any kind of encapsulation and leaves implementation of the `Group` class wide open. Such design may be really difficult to support in future.
2. Add method that returns reference or pointer to the desired `Character` object:

   ```
   class Group
   {
       public:
           int AddCharacter (const Character& i_character) {
               int character_id = characterList.size ();

               characterList.push_back (i_character);

               return character_id;
           }

           Character& Character (int i_character_id) {
               return characterList [i_character_id];
           }

       private:
           vector<Character> characterList;
   }
   ```

   This design is a little bit better, because it does not reveal the actual implementation of the `Group` class. However, using character name as an identifier might be a better solution.

   Character ID may be retrieved from the `Group::AddCharacter()` method:

   ```
   ...
   Group group (...);
   Character character (...);       

   auto character_id = group.AddCharacter (character);

   group.Character (character_id).SetName ("new name");
   ...
   ```

   Note, that you do not name the method `PushCharacterToVector()` but `AddCharacter`. This hides the actual implementation that might change in the future and is easier to understand when reading the code.